# Python - parse string with letters and digits to float

Tags: python, parsing

I have a this: ('56.5T', '181G') I would like to seperate it and parse digits to float and if we have T as last char I would like to transfer it to gb so do the 56.5*1024 and result write to float. if Last char is G just parse it.

And now the whole structure looks like this:

```
 input = 'HV01': [('c50', '8G', '118G'),
          ('c5d0', '26G', '22.3G')],
         'HV02': [('c5t6005Dd0', '790G', '162G'),
          ('c5t60', '203G', '34.8G'),
          ('c5t6d0', '56.5T', '112G')]
```

So its a tuple in a list in a dictionary.
what Im doing is geting to specific values in a for loop like this:

```
for i in dict.keys():
 for j in (dict[i]):
    if j[1] == "*G" || j[2] == "something":
        print ("SOME MOGIC TO HAPPEN")
```

Comment: Please can you **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49917193/edit)** your post with input *and* desired output? As it stands, this question is unclear.

Comment: What if `'56.5TG'`

Comment: I don't see any tuple item ending with `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an already existing parsing library, specifically written to deal with cases like this: [`humanfriendly`](https://pypi.org/project/humanfriendly/):

```
from humanfriendly import parse_size
for s in ["5.6T", "4.9G"]:
    print(parse_size(s) / int(1E9), "G")
# 5600.0 G
# 4.9 G
```

And in your specific case:

```
from humanfriendly import parse_size, InvalidSize

def parse(x):
    try:
        return parse_size(x) / int(1E9)
    except InvalidSize:
        # anything that is not a size, like the first string
        return x

d = {'HV01': [('c50', '8G', '118G'),
              ('c5d0', '26G', '22.3G')],
     'HV02': [('c5t6005Dd0', '790G', '162G'),
              ('c5t60', '203G', '34.8G'),
              ('c5t6d0', '56.5T', '112G')]}

for values in d.values():
    for line in values:
        print(" ".join("{}G".format(parse(x)) for x in line))
# c50 8.0G 118.0G
# c5d0 26.0G 22.3G
# c5t6005Dd0 790.0G 162.0G
# c5t60 203.0G 34.8G
# c5t6d0 56500.0G 112.0G
```

Use `2**30` instead of `int(1E9)` if you want to use the binary prefixes instead of the decimal ones.

Comment: the problem is that I cant use this library. Any other Ideas ?

Comment: @MieszkoCzerniak Why not? even without admin privileges, you can still do `pip install --local humanfriendly`. Or is it an assignment and specified that no external libraries are allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Note : You cannot modify the elements of a tuple. So, if I take the tuple element(which has a T) as a list, then your problem of changing the `T` to `G` can be solved like below:

```
import re

s = {'HV01': [['c50', '8G', '118G'],['c5d0', '26G', '22.3G']],
         'HV02': [['c5t6005Dd0', '790G', '162G'],['c5t60', '203G', '34.8G'],['c5t6d0', '56.5T', '112G']]}

k = s.keys()
v = s.values()

for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(v[i])):
        for k in range(len(v[i][j])):

            if 'T' in v[i][j][k]:
                res = re.sub("T","G",v[i][j][k])
                v[i][j][k] = str(float(res.split('G')[0]) * 1024

            elif 'G' in v[i][j][k]:
                res = v[i][j][k]
                res = re.sub("G","T",v[i][j][k])
                v[i][j][k] = float(res.split('T')[0])
            else :
                pass
print s
```

The output, if you print `s` is :

```
{'HV02': [['c5t6005Dd0', 790.0, 162.0], ['c5t60', 203.0, 34.8], ['c5t6d0', '57856.0', 112.0]], 'HV01': [['c50', 8.0, 118.0], ['c5d0', 26.0, 22.3]]}
```

The values in TBs are changed to GBs and the values in GBs remain as-is without the `T` or `G` extensions.

Comment: Its not exactly what I meant: the simplest way when T transfere terabytes to gigabytes and remove letter "T" leaving just digits, if G just remove letter "G" leaving just digits:

Comment: @MieszkoCzerniak, I have changed the code. Now the entire dictionary is just the digits showing sizes in GBs.